# AR9485 network driver giving very weak wifi signal 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, lenovo

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo Ideapad Z500 and I am constantly getting a very weak wifi signal. This happens even when very close to the router (getting 2 bars sitting 20cm away) and the wifi totally drops at any moderate distance. I had the same issue on Windows 10 but was unable to reinstall my drivers or anything because Win10 was not supported.

This persists across all networks (I have been connected to at least 4 different home networks with exactly the same problems) and is not an issue with other devices.

I am very unsure of what to do, whether I need to play with some system settings or if I need to reinstall / change drivers. I am quite afraid of breaking something haha.

The output of `sudo lshw -C network` is

```
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 01
   serial: a4:db:30:0e:1d:8e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.8.0-46-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:d3900000-d397ffff memory:d3980000-d398ffff
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm a bit fed up with this laptop (has given me a lot of issues) and am just experimenting with Ubuntu to see how it goes.

Comment: *I had the same issue on Windows 10*... If so you should perhaps start by troubleshooting the hardware as this has nothing to with Ubuntu.

Comment: @CelticWarrior is correct.   Check to insure that the antenna leads are properly connected to your wifi card and that the card itself is properly seated in it's slot (since you have it open checking the antenna leads)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is hardware related and not about Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm having the same problem it seems, `iwconfig` shows that the bitrate is set low (1Mbit/6Mbit usually), some days it'll work, most days it's pretty bad. I didn't used to have many problems with it on windows, but after moving to linux mint wireless networking has been a massive headache. I've been scouring the internet for weeks now without success.

Comment: I have this same issue for AR9485 with ubuntu 16.04, Works fine with Windows